# Grouping based on pattern Sql

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Say I have the following table name **t1(deptName,courseName,fund)** I want to get sum of fund of each courseName with its deptName.So far all  I can do is group by courseName and sum(fund) to get sum of fund under each courseName but how can I also include deptName on each output row like deptName,CourseName sum(fund)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility: concatenate deptName and courseName and group by that (that literally fulfills what you are asking).

```
SELECT deptName + '_' + courseName as Dept_Course, SUM(fund)
FROM t1
GROUP BY (deptName + '_' + courseName)
```

Or (thanks @giorgi):

```
SELECT deptName + '_' + courseName as Dept_Course, SUM(fund)
FROM t1
GROUP BY deptName,courseName
```

Usually, you can just do this, though:

```
SELECT deptName,courseName,SUM(fund)
FROM t1
GROUP BY deptName,courseName
```

Comment: Thanks.Is there any other way?Not necessarily I need to do it in single query.I am returning the result from a store procedure so few quries is ok for me or I can use temp table if I have to.Any more suggestion?

Comment: I added a second option that simply groups by both columns.  Does that work for you?

Comment: No need to group on expression. this will work SELECT deptName + '_' + courseName,SUM(fund)
FROM t1
GROUP BY deptName,courseName

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri is right.  You can group on just the columns and have a calculated result in the SELECT

Comment: and sorry I couldnt vote up your ans as I have less than 15 reputation